# Is it possible to extend and customize a mobile service provider's network?

Tags: networking, signal-processing, telecommunication, cellular-network, 4g

I have tried asking around but I can't seem to find the answer that fits my situation.

I am in a rural area and the network here is terrible.

I want to extend the existing telecommunication companys' signal and customize its use in the extended area.

Like creating a LAN where you can customize the functions in your LAN before the user data gets through your Internet Access Point to the ISP.

To clarify, let me give an **Example Scenario**: Let's say a villager wants to use my extended network. The network should be able to verify if the user has registered to use the extended network service and give them access to the extended service's USSD apps, internet access(through the existing ISP) and more.

If u have a hint or the actual answer, please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it may be possible to use an existing ISP connection to be the 'gateway' for your extended network, but business rules and legal restrictions are quite likely to be a barrier.

Many ISP's will have wording in their terms and conditions to prevent you sharing or reselling bandwidth on your connection, and they quite often will have configuration to restrict number of connections and detection tools to identify unusual traffic patterns also.

However, the ISP may actually have a service that will allow you operate a local network and backhaul the traffic through their network - if you feel the local ISP is approachable it might be a good starting point to discuss it with them.

Comment: That's some good input Mick. However my main question is, how would one implement such a solution and would it be expensive?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy answer to that - at one end of spectrum you could simply share your wifi password and network ID and at the other you could have a full peering agreement with the ISP and run your portion like an operator, using a ful model e.g. https://inform.tmforum.org/digital-transformation-and-maturity/2014/10/future-business-process-framework-etom/ It depends on what you want to offer, how you manage it and the agreement you have with the ISP.